# Clean environment for bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, slurm

Is there a way to tell a bash script not to import any variables from the parent shell i.e. ignore exported variables. There is such capability in slurm `--export=NONE` so I wonder if there is an option I can put in the `#!/bin/bash` line to get similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux the cleanest option I found was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S - bash
env
```

which for me prints:

```
PWD=/home/allan
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Another option is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ -n "$HOME" ] && exec -c "$0"
env
```

Possible using `$BASH_SOURCE[0]` instead of `$0` as the latter can be set by user. $BASH_SOURCE, however, is not always set.  Hard-coding the script path would work but that's ugly.

Comment: Note that it isn't guaranteed across operating systems that a shebang can take that many arguments. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399697/3113; in the docs in links: *For portable use, optional-arg should either be absent, or be specified as a single word (i.e., it should not contain white space)*

Comment: BTW, think about `"${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-$0}"` to use `BASH_SOURCE` (more reliable than `$0`) when available. There's discussion of the caveats associated with $0 in [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028#Why_.240_is_NOT_an_option).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for both comments.  If you fallback on $0 what's the point?

Comment: This `[ -n "$HOME" ] && exec -c "$0" "$@"` worked for me from a tcsh login shell. The other one only worked from bash login. May I ask why we need to check for $HOME?

Comment: @danny, if you don't do a check of some sort to detect if your environment has already been cleared you'd end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: @AllanWind, _shrug_ -- it's a balancing act on the fallback; having it there means you're sometimes using an incorrect value (and presumably failing); _not_ having it there means you're sometimes giving up when you might otherwise succeed. It's still an advantage over just going direct to $0 insofar as it means one uses a value the shell is confident in when the parent process passed an outright-wrong argv[0] or such.

Comment: In your first approach, I wonder which operating system you are using. The `env` from the GNU coreutils don't have an option `-S`. Instead you would have to specify the option `-i` (i.e. start with empty environment), so it would be `env -i bash`.

Comment: @user1934428 Debian 11 (stable) and /usr/bin/env comes from (GNU) coreutils 8.32-4.  `#!/usr/bin/env -s bash` gave me an error.